# Page Scrolling Not Working on Android Device

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating cross platform mobile apps using *phonegap framework*.The following codes are used for page scrolling.

```
.page{overflow-y: scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
```

It's working on ios device good. In Android devices, the page scrolling is not working.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The script development began because mobile webkit (on iPhone, iPad, Android) does not provide a native way to scroll content inside a fixed width/height element.

So you use [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
.page{ overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
```

In Android ICS+ this has worked for me.